# Get Driver Locked memory programmatically

Tags: windows, winapi, memory

How can I get `Driver Locked` memory programmatically? WMI, WinApi anyway?

[image: This information displayed by rammap from sysinternals utils]

Comment: Process Hacker 2 is open source, read its code

Comment: I can't find any information about Driver Locked in process hacker

Comment: Why do you need this information?

Comment: Fair enough. The programs are usually pretty interchangeable and I often find that the source code for Process Hacker shows you how to do things that can be seen in procexp. Although I can now see that RAM map is not part of procexp.

Comment: @Michael, for diagnostic tools which i developing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

really not hard debug *RAMMap[64].exe* and view how it get this results. note - all used structures and api classes here undocumented. so as is. all data types declared in [processhacker](https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/tree/master/phnt/include) project. i will be use it as is : [`#include <phnt.h>`](https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/blob/master/phnt/include/phnt.h)

also in [*ntmmapi.h*](https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/blob/master/phnt/include/ntmmapi.h) we can view next constants:

```
#define MMPFNUSE_PROCESSPRIVATE 0
#define MMPFNUSE_FILE 1
#define MMPFNUSE_PAGEFILEMAPPED 2
#define MMPFNUSE_PAGETABLE 3
#define MMPFNUSE_PAGEDPOOL 4
#define MMPFNUSE_NONPAGEDPOOL 5
#define MMPFNUSE_SYSTEMPTE 6
#define MMPFNUSE_SESSIONPRIVATE 7
#define MMPFNUSE_METAFILE 8
#define MMPFNUSE_AWEPAGE 9
#define MMPFNUSE_DRIVERLOCKPAGE 10
#define MMPFNUSE_KERNELSTACK 11
```

if compare it with screenshot - visible match.

tool first query physical memory ranges (displayed in 5 tab ) via ([`SystemSuperfetchInformation`](https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/blob/master/phnt/include/ntexapi.h#L1320), [`SuperfetchMemoryRangesQuery`](https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/blob/master/phnt/include/ntpfapi.h#L240)) and than for every page (range) do query [`SuperfetchPfnQuery`](https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/blob/master/phnt/include/ntpfapi.h#L229).

minimal code can look like:

```
NTSTATUS Rammap(PF_PHYSICAL_MEMORY_RANGE_INFO* ppmri, ULONGLONG Use[16], DWORD dwPageSize)
{
    if (ULONG RangeCount = ppmri->RangeCount)
    {
        WCHAR kb[64];
        ULONG_PTR TotalSize = 0;

        PF_PHYSICAL_MEMORY_RANGE* Range = ppmri->Ranges;

        PF_PFN_PRIO_REQUEST pprr = {
            PF_PFN_PRIO_REQUEST_VERSION
        };

        SUPERFETCH_INFORMATION spi = {
            SUPERFETCH_INFORMATION_VERSION, SUPERFETCH_INFORMATION_MAGIC, SuperfetchPfnQuery, &pprr, sizeof(pprr)
        };

        do 
        {
            if (ULONG_PTR PageCount = Range->PageCount)
            {
                ULONG_PTR PfnCount;
                ULONG_PTR BasePfn = Range->BasePfn;

                ULONG_PTR 
                    Start = BasePfn * dwPageSize, 
                    Size = PageCount * dwPageSize,
                    End = Start + Size;

                TotalSize += Size;

                StrFormatKBSize(Size, kb, RTL_NUMBER_OF(kb));

                DbgPrint("0x%016I64x\t0x%016I64x\t%S\n", Start, End, kb);

                do 
                {
                    pprr.PfnCount = PfnCount = min(PageCount, RTL_NUMBER_OF(pprr.PageData));

                    MMPFN_IDENTITY* PageData = pprr.PageData;

                    do 
                    {
                        PageData++->PageFrameIndex = BasePfn++;
                    } while (--PfnCount);

                    ULONG cb;

                    NTSTATUS status = NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemSuperfetchInformation, &spi, sizeof(spi), &cb);

                    if (0 <= status)
                    {
                        PageData = pprr.PageData;
                        PfnCount = pprr.PfnCount;
                        do 
                        {                           
                            Use[PageData++->u1.e1.UseDescription]++;
                        } while (--PfnCount);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return status;
                    }

                } while (PageCount -= pprr.PfnCount);
            }

        } while (Range++, --RangeCount);

        StrFormatKBSize(TotalSize, kb, RTL_NUMBER_OF(kb));

        DbgPrint("-------------\nTotalSize: %S\n", kb);

    }

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

NTSTATUS Rammap(ULONGLONG Use[16], DWORD dwPageSize)
{
    BOOLEAN b;
    NTSTATUS status = RtlAdjustPrivilege(SE_PROF_SINGLE_PROCESS_PRIVILEGE, TRUE, FALSE, &b);

    if (0 <= status)
    {
        SUPERFETCH_INFORMATION spi = {
            SUPERFETCH_INFORMATION_VERSION, SUPERFETCH_INFORMATION_MAGIC, SuperfetchMemoryRangesQuery
        };

        ULONG rcb = sizeof(PF_PHYSICAL_MEMORY_RANGE_INFO);

        static volatile UCHAR guz = 0;

        PVOID stack = alloca(guz);

        PF_PHYSICAL_MEMORY_RANGE_INFO* ppmri = 0;

        do 
        {
            if (spi.Length < rcb)
            {
                spi.Length = RtlPointerToOffset(spi.Data = alloca(rcb - spi.Length), stack);
                ppmri = (PF_PHYSICAL_MEMORY_RANGE_INFO*)spi.Data;
                ppmri->Version = PF_PHYSICAL_MEMORY_RANGE_INFO_VERSION;
            }

            if (0 <= (status = NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemSuperfetchInformation, &spi, sizeof(spi), &rcb)))
            {
                status = Rammap(ppmri, Use, dwPageSize);
                break;
            }
        } while (status == STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL);
    }

    return status;
}

void Rammap()
{
    SYSTEM_INFO sbi;
    GetSystemInfo(&sbi);
    ULONGLONG Use[16]={};
    if (0 <= Rammap(Use, sbi.dwPageSize))
    {
        WCHAR sz[16], kb[32];
        PCWSTR Name;
        ULONG n = MMPFNUSE_KERNELSTACK;
        do 
        {
            ULONGLONG u = Use[n];

            switch (n)
            {
            case MMPFNUSE_PROCESSPRIVATE: Name = L"Process Private";
                break;
            case MMPFNUSE_FILE: Name = L"Mapped File";
                break;
            case MMPFNUSE_PAGEFILEMAPPED: Name = L"Shareable";
                break;
            case MMPFNUSE_PAGETABLE: Name = L"Page Tabe";
                break;
            case MMPFNUSE_PAGEDPOOL: Name = L"Page Pool";
                break;
            case MMPFNUSE_NONPAGEDPOOL: Name = L"NonPaged Pool";
                break;
            case MMPFNUSE_SYSTEMPTE: Name = L"System PTE";
                break;
            case MMPFNUSE_SESSIONPRIVATE: Name = L"Session Private";
                break;
            case MMPFNUSE_METAFILE: Name = L"Metafile";
                break;
            case MMPFNUSE_AWEPAGE: Name = L"AWE";
                break;
            case MMPFNUSE_DRIVERLOCKPAGE: Name = L"DriverLocked";
                break;
            case MMPFNUSE_KERNELSTACK: Name = L"KernelStack";
                break;
            default:
                swprintf(sz, L"[%x]", n);
                Name = sz;
            }

            StrFormatKBSize(u * sbi.dwPageSize, kb, RTL_NUMBER_OF(kb));
            DbgPrint("%16S %S\n", Name, kb);
        } while (n--);
    }
}
```

for self system i got

```
0x0000000000001000  0x0000000000058000  348 KB
0x0000000000059000  0x000000000009f000  280 KB
0x0000000000100000  0x000000008122c000  2,114,736 KB
0x000000008122e000  0x000000008a2d1000  148,108 KB
0x000000008a60a000  0x000000008a772000  1,440 KB
0x000000008b3ff000  0x000000008b400000  4 KB
0x0000000100000000  0x000000046f000000  14,401,536 KB
-------------
TotalSize: 16,666,452 KB
     KernelStack 24,400 KB
    DriverLocked 13,768 KB
             AWE 0 KB
        Metafile 667,932 KB
 Session Private 24,048 KB
      System PTE 50,332 KB
   NonPaged Pool 323,104 KB
       Page Pool 314,032 KB
       Page Tabe 69,020 KB
       Shareable 243,288 KB
     Mapped File 4,391,092 KB
 Process Private 10,545,436 KB
```